# flutter contextual text direction

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to have contextual text direction, that means in current text direction, no matter `LRT` or `RTL` the direction sets based on the content of the text

If we have the following code

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    const Text('English'), // Always LTR
    const Text('فارسی'), // Always RTL
    Text(stringVriableMaybeLtrMaybeRtl), // Based on content, May be LTR may be RTL
  ],
)
```

As there is asked in comments for mix of both see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text

Comment: Did you try? What happens if `stringVriableMaybeLtrMaybeRtl` for example is a mix of both?

Comment: As have been mentioned this would be problematic if you have mixed text. However, if you are certain or indifferent about that you can check based on unicode, and then wrap with `Directionality`

Comment: @nvoigt see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025915/6447123 that use `intl.Bidi.detectRtlDirectionality`  but may be there is better option